# d3.js: Passing data from parent node to child node onclick event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to make a stacked bar chart.

Thanks to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662756/d3-js-passing-data-from-parent-to-child-nodes) I am binding data associated with a parent node to a child node using parentNode.__ data__.key.

The data is an array with one object for each bar (e.g 'likes').  Then each object contains an array of values which drive the individual rectangles per bar:

```
data =  [{
          key = 'likes', values = [
            {key = 'blue-frog', value = 1}, 
            {key = 'goodbye', value = 2}
          ]
        }, {
          key = 'dislikes, values = [
            {key = 'blue-frog', value = 3},
            {key = 'goodbye', value = 4}
          ]
        }]
```

The chart is working fine, and so is binding the parent metric data to a child svg attribute:

```
// Create canvas
bars = svg.append("g");

// Create individual bars, and append data
// 'likes' are bound to first bar, 'dislikes' to second
bar = bars.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)        
        .enter()
        .append("g");

// Create rectangles per bar, and append data
// 'blue-frog' is bound to first rectangle, etc.
rect = bar.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d.values;})
        .enter()
        .append("rect");

// Append parent node information (e.g. 'likes') to each rectangle    
// per the SO question referenced above        
rect.attr("metric", function(d, i, j) {
  return rect[j].parentNode.__data__.key;
});
```

This then allows the creation of tooltips per rectangle which say things like "likes: 2."  So far so good.

The problem is how to associate this same information with a click event, building on:

```
rect.on("click", function(d) {
  return _this.onChartClick(d);
});

// or

rect.on("click", this.onChartClick.bind(this));
```

It's problematic because the onChartClick method needs access to the bound data (d) and the chart execution context ('this').  If it didn't I could just switch the execution context and call `d3.select(this).attr("metric")` within the onChartClick method.

Another idea I had was to pass the metric as an additional parameter but the trick of using function(d, i, j) here doesn't seem to work because it isn't run until a click event happens.

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the closure to keep a reference to the parent data like this:

```
bar.each(function(dbar) {            // dbar refers to the data bound to the bar
  d3.select(this).selectAll("rect")
      .on("click", function(drect) { // drect refers to the data bound to the rect
        console.log(dbar.key);       // dbar.key will be either 'likes' or 'dislikes'
      });
});
```

update:

See below for various ways to access different levels in your DOM structure. Mix and match! See the live version of this and try to click on the .rect divs: http://bl.ocks.org/4235050

```
var data =  [
    {
        key: 'likes',
        values: [{ key: 'blue-frog', value: 1 }, { key: 'goodbye', value: 2 }]
    }, 
    {
        key: 'dislikes',
        values: [{ key: 'blue-frog', value: 3 }, { key: 'goodbye', value: 4 }]
    }];

var chartdivs = d3.select("body").selectAll("div.chart")
    .data([data]) // if you want to make multiple charts: .data([data1, data2, data3])
  .enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .style("width", "500px")
    .style("height", "400px");

chartdivs.call(chart); // chartdivs is a d3.selection of one or more chart divs. The function chart is responsible for creating the contents in those divs

function chart(selection) { // selection is one or more chart divs
  selection.each(function(d,i) { // for each chartdiv do the following
    var chartdiv = d3.select(this);
    var bar = chartdiv.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(d)
      .enter().append("div")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .style("width", "100px")
        .style("height", "100px")
        .style("background-color", "red");  

    var rect = bar.selectAll(".rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
      .enter().append("div")
        .attr("class", "rect")
        .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
        .style("background-color", "steelblue");

    bar.each(function(dbar) {
      var bardiv = d3.select(this);
      bardiv.selectAll(".rect")
          .on("click", function(drect) { 
            d3.select(this).call(onclickfunc, bardiv);
          });
    });

    function onclickfunc(rect, bar) { // has access to chart, bar, and rect
      chartdiv.style("background-color", bar.datum().key === 'likes' ? "green" : "grey");
      console.log(rect.datum().key); // will print either 'blue-frog' or 'goodbye'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is very helpful.  I'm afraid I'm still stuck though on how to reference the onChartClick function in the middle of this. This lives in the overall chart / class context, not the rectangle.

Comment: I was just looking at it.  Truly a masterclass!  It's going to take me a little time to go through it and make sure I understand.  I was wondering, what do you think the title of this question should have been?

Comment: Ok. First (and basic) question.  What's going on with chartdivs.call(chart)?  chartdivs isn't a function, yet the syntax for call is [fun.call(args)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).  I'm sure I've missed something simple here.

Comment: One thing that might be confusing is that in d3 code you'll encounter two different types of 'call' methods:

There is the d3 selection's method: selection.call(function[, arguments…])
( https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-call )

and there is the Javascript's Function method: fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call )

So, this is the selection.call method your are looking at. The chartdivs is a d3.selection on which we are calling the function chart. This construct is used a lot in D3.

Answer (score 0):

`rect.on("click", this.onChartClick.bind(this));` won't work because you're not passing a function, you're passing the return value of the function (by appending `(this)`).

If you want to pass `this` and data (`d`), try this:

```
// assuming you have this somewhere earlier
var onChartClick = function () {}

// change your parent click to
rect.on("click", function(d) {
    return onChartClick.call(this, d);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brian.  The bit I'm struggling with is not just passing data and this, it's passing data, this AND the metric information (e.g. 'likes')

Comment: The value of likes is (i.e. 2), but the key (i.e. 'likes') is at the top level of the data.  This means that 'likes' are bound to first bar, 'dislikes' to second etc.  Then what gets bound to each rectangle within the bar is e.g. {key = 'blue-frog', value = 1}, i.e. no information that this refers to 'likes'  I could change the data, but this is used in multiple places, so I would prefer to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be f.e passing an object/json or in my case a class instance which creates that rectangle to the event to access it inside

```
var rect = svgContainer.append("rect");
rect.datum(this);
rect.on('click', function(d){
    alert(d);
    alert(d.id); // etc.
});
```