# d3.js: how to use data from the parent node? (to show the grouped bar name at the individual bar tooltip)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a grouped column chart in [this notebook](https://observablehq.com/@openinfo/german-election-data-in-a-column-chart).

The columns are grouped per groupKey (year in this case).

How to show the groupKey in the tooltip per column? (I can show the column key and value)

I can see that the data is bound to the parentNode "g":

[image]

```
var groups = svg.append("g")
.selectAll("g")
.data(data)
.join("g")
  .attr("transform", d => 'translate(' + x0(d[groupKey]) + ',0)')
  .attr("class", "barsgroup");
```

So when I add the rect for each column:

```
 var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d => keys.map(key => ({key, value: d[key]})))
    .join("rect")
      .attr("x", d => x1(d.key))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.value))
      .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))
      .append("title")
      .text(d => d.key + ": " + d.value);
      //.text(function (d, i, node) {return node.parentNode.__data__.value + ", " + d.key + ": " + d.value});
```

I would like to access the groupkey (year) from the original data. But the data bound to the rect are just the keys & values (within each group) so I do not have the groupkey and groupkey value at this level. My attempts to get it from the parent "g" element were like:

```
//.text(function (d, i, node) {return node.parentNode.__data__.value + ", " + d.key + ": " + d.value});
```

This is based on several sources, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662756/d3-js-passing-data-from-parent-to-child-nodes) and [this description](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection) but I cannot work it out.

Please help? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, nice work, because you almost got it! I've forked your [notebook](https://observablehq.com/@iblind/grouped-column-chart-how-to-show-the-groupkey-in-the-tooltip) to clarify, but essentially, you only traversed the DOM up a single level, and hadn't yet reached the higher level.

Here's the relevant snippet:

```js
.text((d,i,n) => {

const yearNode = d3.select(n[i])
.node()
.parentNode
.parentNode

const selectedYear = d3.select(yearNode)
.data()[0]
.Year

console.log(selectedYear);

        d.key + ": " + d.value
      });
```

As you can see, the above code moves up two parent nodes, first to the `rect` element and then to the `g` element.

Next, we select this node using d3, access its data attributes using the `.data()` method, and get the year value using the `Year` key.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have corrected 2 things: 1. Added return selectedYear + ', '  to the final "d.key + ": " + d.value" (otherwise the title text does not display). And 2. changed d.year to d.Year on the nestedData (which I assume is added by you just for info purposes but interesting to see!)